# find series and shunt components of matching network

Tags: impedance-matching

hello there i am trying to solve this question. i have uploaded question and solution here.
correct answer is X1 = -j25 and X2 = j30.
can you tell me why am i wrong??
can you help me to solve this??

[image]

my solution is here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement in the question tells you \$ Z_{out}^{*} = Z_{in} \$ where \$ Z_{in} = X_{2} + R_{1}X_{1}/(R_{1}+X_{1})\$.

You also know \$ X_{1} \$ and \$ X_{2}  \$ are only imaginary, therefore you can split the equation for \$ Z_{in} \$ in real and imaginary parts to get 2 equations, repectivly to \$ X_{1} \$ and \$ X_{2}  \$.
Now you can solve the equation system and you will get the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

I tried to solve it this way. but i am not getting right answer. can you correct me??

**Zin = X2+ R1.X1/(R1+X1)**

Zin = (X2.R1+ X2.X1 +R1.X1)/(R1+X1)

10-j10 = (50X2 +X2.X1+50X1)/(50+X1)

(50X2+50x1)/(50+X1) = -10

50X2+50X1 = -500-10.X1

60X1+50X2 = -500

6X1+5X2 = -50  ----------------------equation(1)

10 = X2.X1/(50+X1)

500+10X1 = X2.X1

(500+10X1)/X1 = X2  -------------------equation(2)

Comment: First Zin = 10+j10 and i would multiply the fraction by the complex conjungate to get a real valued denomiantor, and only then split the equation in real and imaginary part. You don't have to multiply X2 with the whole fraction, that only complicates things

Comment: Thanks. i got correct answer. I have one question that how to consider sign?? like my X1 is negative

Comment: since X1 is only imaginary there is no problem with a negative sign

Comment: X1 and X2 both are imaginary

Comment: I don't see your problem with the sign?